# Ubuntu - how to recover interrupted do-release-upgrade during download phase

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, I wanted to upgrade to Ubuntu 22 using `do-release-upgrade`.
I started the process but the download was very slow. So, at about 5% of the download phase I interrupted the process to change mirrors. I don't think any packages have been installed yet, so I thought it would be fine to interrupt the process and run it again to resume it.

Now if I run `do-release-upgrade` it just says:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

`lsb_release -a` still says I'm on 20.04:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I see that `/etc/apt/sources.list` points to `jammy` repositories, so I guess that's why `do-release-upgrade` asks me to download "all the available updates".

What is the correct way to recover here?

Comment: Are you are to just restart the entire process again?

Comment: If I run `do-release-upgrade` again it just shows that output and exits. I guess I should modify my `/etc/apt/sources.list` jammy entries to focal and run it again. I'm just asking to make sure I'm not missing any extra steps, I don't want to break everything.

Comment: Does Ubuntu Recovery Mode help here at all?      https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: If you have the option, the quickest and safest is to restore the disk image made just prior to the attempt at upgrade. Failing that, use the Synaptic Package Manager or terminal to make sure there are no invalid packages and repair any. *Then* try the upgrade again.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Do you get a message about "packages have been kept back"? If this happens, try to `sudo apt install` them, and if the problem persists then uninstall with `sudo apt remove` and then install back.

Comment: The computer is still turned on, and I don't think I need recovery to boot as nothing was installed so far I think. I have backups of my data but not a disk image. @harrymc Will this be the same as completing the `do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: If it works, it will first undo the interrupted update and may install/upgrade the blocking packages in advance of the rest.

Comment: Ciao, welcome on SuperUser. Try to clear cache. Start with `sudo apt clean` `sudo apt -f install` and check online on how to clear apt cache. If it doesn't restart after this, look at info on how to clear dpkg cache. Then go through the downloaded and not installed packages. After each step try to rerun `do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just done the exact same thing. The solution, if you killed the process before it finished downloading, is to revert `/etc/sources.list` to point to your current release and not the new one you are upgrading to.

Fortunately, `do-release-upgrade` does create a backup before updating (editing) it to point to the new release. It's called `sources.list.distUpgrade`. You just have to rename it back to `sources.list` and then do an `apt update`. Running `apt upgrade` should tell you that there is nothing to upgrade and at this point, you can run `do-release-upgrade` again.